# can we have criteria inside a criteria query in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate, where to fetch data i am using criteria. but i think there are some restrictions using criteria. but i want to ask below things that i feel could be possible by using criteria in hibernate.

how below query can be written in criteria base hibernate

```
select * from (select d.priceId , sum(d.price) as sumP, avg(d.price) as  avgP from data d group by d.priceId) as adata where sumP like '%%';
```

as for now i can write criteria base hibernate query for below SQL:

```
select d.priceId , sum(d.price) as sumP, avg(d.price) as  avgP from data d group by d.priceId
```

as below

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
criteria = session.createCriteria(Data.class, "data")
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.groupProperty("d.priceId"))
.add(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(d.price) as sumP", new String[] {"sumP"},new org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType[] {new org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType()}), "sumP")
.add(Projections.sqlProjection("avg(d.price) as avgP", new String[] {"avgP"},new org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType[] {new org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType()}), "avgP"));
```

then how to write criteria based query for below SQL:

```
 select * from (select d.priceId , sum(d.price) as sumP, avg(d.price) as  avgP from data d group by d.priceId) as adata where sumP like '%%';
```

Please help me on above.

Comment: You're using Hibernate API, not JPA API, so don't tag as JPA

Answer (score 0):

I did not think HQL could do subqueries in the from clause

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries

Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.
I imagine you could change it to a native query and execute it that way.